# python/pandas: moved a script, get attribute error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, python-wheel

I have a working script on one system (python2.7, pandas 16), but when I moved it to a different system with python2.7 and pandas 17, the following line --

```
 df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].map(lambda x: pd.datetools.parse(x))
```

generates the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

I tried to remove pandas17 and load 16 but the whl file -- pandas.0.16.2-cp27-none-win32.whl -- "is not a supported wheel on this platform"

It looks like a versioning issue. Anything else I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

Comment: Thanks again, Andy. Does this reflect a change in pandas 17?

Comment: @mattrweaver this has been around a long time (the right/pandas way to do it), I'll have a look at whether there was a change to datetools.